# What is the default indent size in an Excel cell?

Tags: .net, excel, pdf, syncfusion

I'm trying to convert xlsx file to PDF using syncfusion version 16 on .NET, but after converting the PDF file has almost no padding in the table cell. I would like to know what is the default indent size? Perhaps it can be seen somewhere?
Excel: [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPq6.png)
PDF: [pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUi7Q.png)

I tried to find it myself in the Excel documentation, in Excel xml files, but unfortunately without success.

Comment: There's no such thing - or rather, it's 0. Excel's job is to display and process data, not provide pixel-perfect rendering like a word processor or HTML. The `Indent` setting in a cell's format doesn't refer to any explicit unit.

Comment: What code did you use? How did you generate the PDF? PDF isn't a document format, it's a file containing print (Postscript) commands. There are no tables, much less indents, in PDF. You can't "convert" other data formats to PDF. When *Excel* saves to PDF it actually renders the workbook and *prints* it to Postscript, packaging the output in a PDF file. Rendering is the job of the application itself.